# Browserify ES6 code without gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm using [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) with ES5 code

```
$> browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

But now I would like to do the same thing with ES6. With gulp this is easy:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify(....)
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Is it possible to use this command line tool to handle ES6 code ?

UPDATE:

Here are the files from my test project:

index.js:

```
import test from 'test';

test();
```

test.js:

```
export default function doit(msg = 'default msg')  {
    alert(`x: ${msg}`);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><head>

    <body>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Now If I run the suggested command:

```
$> browserify index.js -o bundle.js -t babelify --presets es2015
index.js:1
import test from 'test';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Check the `-t` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] origin.js -o destination.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've updated my question, because I cannot get it to work yet.

Comment: Probably you need to install the babel preset, did you install it? `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: Hmmm, you miss the "[" in the -t option. Check my example. I tried it in my project and it worked.